# Configuring MySQL to run scripts upon start or restart

Tags: mysql, linux, database

Is there a possibility or MySQL configuration that I can do such that whenever I start or restart my MySQL server , it automatically run some scripts for me.

Please help , anyone with an idea

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the [init_file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_file) or [init_connect](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_connect) options?

Comment: not yet sir, i will now